# Set mxgraph cell only draggable within the canvas width

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I have multiple vertex cells in the graph. I am using JavaScript library **mxGraph**. When i drag the cell from the boundary of canvas, the canvas extends. I want to disallow the cell drag. Is there some function available to limit the drag within the canvas boundaries?

There is function called: `graph.setCellsMovable(false);` but this one lock overall, i need to set cell movement false only if user drag it outside the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a try to the `mxgraph.autoExtend` property which seems to configure exactly what you are looking for

https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.autoExtend

> Specifies if the size of the graph should be automatically extended if
> the mouse goes near the container edge while dragging.  This is only
> taken into account if the container has scrollbars.  Default is true.

There are also other configuration properties about auto extend, like https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.extendParentsOnAdd