# how to make the parent mxcell in mxgraph javascript library

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am using mxgraph javascript library. Scenario: one swim lane is added to the graph. Any shapes can be added as a child to the swimlane (drag and drop).We can add 'n' number of childs . how to make the swimlane size fixed irrespective of number of childs .When i insert more child vertex in different places, parent mxcell size getting changed.

expected child as below:

[image]

Tried with extendParentsOnAdd/autoextend property. Objects in child are overlap on each other as below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to give a try to the `mxgraph.extendParentsOnAdd` property which seems to configure exactly what you are looking for:
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.extendParentsOnAdd and set it to false

> Specifies if parents should be extended according to the extendParents
> switch if cells are added.  Default is true.

You may also have to configure https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.extendParents

> Specifies if a parent should contain the child bounds after a resize
> of the child.  Default is true.  This has precedence over
> constrainChildren.

There are also other configuration properties about auto extend, like
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.autoExtend (this one is generally useful at graph load time when you provide the intial graph definition)

Notice that this question seems very close to [Set mxgraph cell only draggable within the canvas width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64805220/14299521)

Comment: redfish4ktc ,Thanks for the input.I have already tried those. For more information , i have updated my question with screenshot. Any further inputs can help me

Comment: Could you share a code snippet? the swinlane doesn't appear in the screenshot you provide so it is hard to help on this

Comment: @san did you find any answer to this?